# Makefile: passing different value of variable to same target based on arguments from foreach

Tags: foreach, makefile, gnu-make

**What I want to achieve:**
I have 3 or more tests which needs to be compiled with separate flag[i.e. first test needs to be with -ewp and rest should be -c] by ptxas compiler through same target.

e.g. In below call,div_sc i.e. $1 is the name of executable which depends on $2(div_sc div_sc1 div_sc) . $2 can have multiple test name with space
    $(call ADD_PTXTEST_EWP, div_sc, div_sc div_sc1 div_sc2)

**What I did:**
I have tried the below approach, but only the last value of variable EWP_SC_SETTER is being taken and foreach is failing after first scan of $2

```
Makefile1:
ADD_PTXTEST_EWP = $(eval $(call _ADD_PTXTEST_EWP,$(strip $1),$(strip $2)))
```

### Running foreach for each element in $2.If first element in $2 is equal to $1 then i am setting variable EWP_SC_SETTER = -ewp else EWP_SC_SETTER = -c for target $(1).$(ARCHREV).cubin which is defined in Makefile 2

```
define _ADD_PTXTEST_EWP
$(foreach ptx, $(2), $(if $(filter $1,$(ptx)), $(1).$(ARCHREV).cubin: 
EWP_SC_SETTER = -ewp $(1).$(ARCHREV).cubin: 
$(ptx).$(ARCHREV).$(RELOC_CUBIN_EXTN)$(NEWLINE), $(1).$(ARCHREV).cubin: 
EWP_SC_SETTER = -c $(1).$(ARCHREV).cubin: 
$(ptx).$(ARCHREV).$(RELOC_CUBIN_EXTIN)$(NEWLINE)))
endef
```

Above one did not help so tried another approach. Unfortunately this also not did not work

```
define _ADD_PTXTEST_EWP
PTXTESTS += $(1)
$(info 1 is $(1))
$(foreach ptx, $(2), $(eval $(call _ADD_PTXTEST_EWP_IMP,$(ptx))))
endef



define _ADD_PTXTEST_EWP_IMP
$(info ptx is $(ptx))
ifeq ($(ptx),div_sc)
$(1).$(ARCHREV).cubin: EWP_SC_SETTER := -ewp
$(info in ptx)
else
$(1).$(ARCHREV).cubin: EWP_SC_SETTER := -c
$(info out ptx)
endif
$(1).$(ARCHREV).cubin: $(ptx).$(ARCHREV).$(RELOC_CUBIN_EXTN)$(NEWLINE)
endef
```

This makefile has the definition of target %.$(ARCHREV).cubin

```
Makefile 2:
%.$(ARCHREV).reloc.cubin: %.$(ARCHREV).ptx
$(call TOOLS_HEADER_DUMP_LOG,PTXAS,cubin)
$(EXE_PREFIX) $(PTXAS) $(call FILE_PTXAS_FLAGS,$*) $(call MAXREG,$*) -arch=sm_$(ARCHREV) **$(EWP_SC_SETTER)** $(G_FLAG) $(patsubst %.reloc.cubin, %.ptx, $@) -o $@ $(call IGNORE_COMPILE_ERR,$*) $(call TOOLS_DUMP_REDIRECT2,2,cubin) $(call PERFTIME_DUMP_REDIRECT, $*.perf.txt)

%.$(ARCHREV).cubin: %.$(ARCHREV)$(RELOC_CUBIN_EXTN) 
$(call TOOLS_HEADER_DUMP_LOG,NVLINK,cubin)
$(EXE_PREFIX) $(NVLINK) $(NVLINK_FLAGS) $(call CNPLIBRARY) $(call FILE_NVLINKFLAGS,$*) $(call MAXREG,$*) -arch=sm_$(ARCHREV) $^ -o $@ $(call IGNORE_LINK_ERR,$*) $(call TOOLS_DUMP_REDIRECT,2,cubin)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do, and how these approaches fail to achieve the goal.

Comment: @Beta  As i mentioned ,I have 2 make files.In Makefile 1 , i call target  %.$(ARCHREV).cubin which is defined in Makefile2

Comment: Please ignore above comment.  @Beta  As i mentioned ,I have 2 make files.In Makefile 1 , i call target  %.$(ARCHREV).cubin which is defined in Makefile2  .%.$(ARCHREV).cubin target depends on %.$(ARCHREV).reloc.cubin which run some command as mentioned in makefile 2. I want to execute target %.$(ARCHREV).reloc.cubin with different values of variable EWP_SC_SETTER based on $(ptx) value which is being provided in Makefile 1.  I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a simple problem wrapped in several layers of unnecessary complication. We may have to iterate several times to find an answer. Consider this makefile:

```
ifeq ($(ptx), div_sc)
 EWP_SC_SETTER = -ewp
else
 EWP_SC_SETTER = -c
endif

cubin:
    @echo using $(EWP_SC_SETTER)
```

You want to do something more, but don't know how. What is it?

**EDIT: second attempt**

How about this?

```
TESTS := alpha beta gamma
TEST_EWP := $(word 1, $(TESTS))

FLAG:=-cj

all-tests: $(TESTS)

$(TEST_EWP): FLAG:=-ewp

$(TESTS):
    @echo running test with $(FLAG)
```

Comment: Thanks,but i don't have div_sc always .in general ,$2 will have 1 or more arguments separated with space . First argument of $2 should run with  EWP_SC_SETTER = -ewp and rest should run EWP_SC_SETTER = -c while calling Target by running in foreach.

Comment: @sandeepnagori: It is still unclear what you want, but this is starting to sound like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have updated the description of problem.Can you please check and let me know the solution